# IntelliJ IDEA: vertical font appears wrong on the tool window buttons

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: tool window button font]

Why the font on the tool window buttons is not displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

There is [an open bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162416) in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker for this specific problem.

Workaround: Go to `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Appearance & Behavior` | `Appearance` and override the default font with something else.

Also make sure you are [running on JetBrains Runtime](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).